# Command to install Wifi Drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I recently Purchased BrosTrend 1200Mbps USB WiFi Network Adapter;
Can any one of you please let me know how to install the Drivers on Workstataion with Ubuntu 16.04 ( Linux) OS
What command is used on the Linux to run the Drivers??

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0329 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C930e
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:d407 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Regards
Sudeep

Answer (score 3):

Please follow this steps:

1. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
2. git clone https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
3. cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. sudo modprobe 8812au

Provided by:
https://www.amazon.com/review/RST7YXG0YX6BJ/ref=ask_dp_lswr_rp_hza